# Creating a SLURM cluster on the Google Cloud Platform (GCP) does not complete installation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, slurm

In the GCP I want to create a SLURM cluster. So I followed the guide here:
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/easy-hpc-clusters-on-gcp-with-slurm

All seems to work, until the step where I ssh into the controller oder login nodes. Logging in itself works:

```
~/slurm-slurm-17.11/contribs/gcp$ gcloud deployment-manager deployments create slurm --config slurm-cluster.yaml
~/slurm-slurm-17.11/contribs/gcp$ gcloud compute ssh controller --zone=us-east1-b  
    Last login: Tue Apr 30 09:50:50 2019 from 194....


                                 SSSSSSS
                                SSSSSSSSS
                                SSSSSSSSS
                                SSSSSSSSS
                        SSSS     SSSSSSS     SSSS
                       SSSSSS               SSSSSS
                       SSSSSS    SSSSSSS    SSSSSS
                        SSSS    SSSSSSSSS    SSSS
                SSS             SSSSSSSSS             SSS
               SSSSS    SSSS    SSSSSSSSS    SSSS    SSSSS
                SSS    SSSSSS   SSSSSSSSS   SSSSSS    SSS
                       SSSSSS    SSSSSSS    SSSSSS
                SSS    SSSSSS               SSSSSS    SSS
               SSSSS    SSSS     SSSSSSS     SSSS    SSSSS
          S     SSS             SSSSSSSSS             SSS     S
         SSS            SSSS    SSSSSSSSS    SSSS            SSS
          S     SSS    SSSSSS   SSSSSSSSS   SSSSSS    SSS     S
               SSSSS   SSSSSS   SSSSSSSSS   SSSSSS   SSSSS
          S    SSSSS    SSSS     SSSSSSS     SSSS    SSSSS    S
    S    SSS    SSS                                   SSS    SSS    S
    S     S                                                   S     S
                SSS
                SSS
                SSS
                SSS
 SSSSSSSSSSSS   SSS   SSSS       SSSS    SSSSSSSSS   SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
SSSSSSSSSSSSS   SSS   SSSS       SSSS   SSSSSSSSSS  SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
SSSS            SSS   SSSS       SSSS   SSSS        SSSS     SSSS     SSSS
SSSS            SSS   SSSS       SSSS   SSSS        SSSS     SSSS     SSSS
SSSSSSSSSSSS    SSS   SSSS       SSSS   SSSS        SSSS     SSSS     SSSS
 SSSSSSSSSSSS   SSS   SSSS       SSSS   SSSS        SSSS     SSSS     SSSS
         SSSS   SSS   SSSS       SSSS   SSSS        SSSS     SSSS     SSSS
         SSSS   SSS   SSSS       SSSS   SSSS        SSSS     SSSS     SSSS
SSSSSSSSSSSSS   SSS   SSSSSSSSSSSSSSS   SSSS        SSSS     SSSS     SSSS
SSSSSSSSSSSS    SSS    SSSSSSSSSSSSS    SSSS        SSSS     SSSS     SSSS



*** Slurm is currently being installed/configured in the background. ***
A terminal broadcast will announce when installation and configuration is
complete.
```

But the installation never finishes, even if I wait for hours or a day. How can this be solved, or how can one find out what the problem is?

Here is the file slurm-cluster.yaml:

```
# Copyright 2017 SchedMD LLC.
# Modified for use with the Slurm Resource Manager.
#
# Copyright 2015 Google Inc. All rights reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# [START cluster_yaml]
imports:
- path: slurm.jinja

resources:
- name: slurm-cluster
  type: slurm.jinja
  properties:
    cluster_name            : google1
    static_node_count       : 2
    max_node_count          : 10
    zone                    : us-east1-b
    region                  : us-east1
    cidr                    : 10.10.0.0/16

    controller_machine_type : n1-standard-2
    compute_machine_type    : n1-standard-2
    login_machine_type      : n1-standard-1

    slurm_version           : 17.11.5
    default_account         : default
    default_users           : ********
    munge_key               : 80bc8a12336e6094ced0cb3b2cb1e9c315d6276350207fecd7c293d4623a87bdba11e6eb38a1856fb78ff8dbd027860600f7df0f0d2c5fd960b4f16a0d3fc567f1 >
#  [END cluster_yaml]
```

Comment: I looked at the tutorial that you linked and it starts with _You may want to customize the deployment manager scripts for your needs. Many cluster parameters can be configured in the included slurm-cluster.yaml file_. Could you show what did you change in the `slurm-cluster.yaml` excluding your account name?

Comment: @DmitriChubarov: Thank you very much for looking into this. I have added the config file as you have requested (all default settings except default_users).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use a SLURM version which is currently available on the SchedMD download page:

https://www.schedmd.com/downloads.php

And specify the parameter accordingly in the slurm-cluster.yaml file.